# Как отправлять данные и ожидать ответ в течение N мс с asyncio.Protocol?

Tags: python, асинхронность

Я не изучал библиотеку asyncio в Python, мне просто надо быстро написать небольшой скрипт. Так что вопрос из разряда "сделайте за меня"...

Скрипт должен обмениваться сообщениями с аппаратным устройством по последовательному порту.  Для этого я нашёл [такую библиотеку](https://pyserial-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), с помощью которой можно сделать класс с callback-функциями, которые вызываются при разных событиях на порту. Далее делаю по примеру из документации:

```
import asyncio
import serial_asyncio
import serial

class OutputProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.receivedEvent = asyncio.Event() 

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.checkPower()

    def data_received(self, data):
        """ Эта функция вызывается, когда в буфере порта появляются какие-то данные.
        Я пока не проверяю, какие именно, просто хочу показать, что 
        именно здесь я определяю, что событие получения ответа наступило."""
        self.receivedEvent.set()

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.transport.loop.stop()

    def checkPower(self):
        """ Здесь я проверяю наличие устройства путём отправки тестовой команды. 
        Если ответ пришёл менее, чем за N мс, то устройство подключено. Если же нет, то
        нужно выполнить действия по его включению."""
        self.transport.write(b'AT\r\n')
        """ Здесь можно было бы вызвать self.receivedEvent.wait, но
        эта функция не имеет аргумента-таймаута. К тому же нет уверенности, что
        этот вызов не заблокирует поток и последующая обработка данных в
        data_received будет возможна. Видел также функцию asyncio.wait_for, но её нужно вызывать из функции, помеченной как async. Как это сделать - не могу понять."""

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = serial_asyncio.create_serial_connection(loop, OutputProtocol, "/dev/serial0", baudrate=19200, timeout=1, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
loop.close()
```

Как определить, пришёл ли ответ в отведённое время?